# Root user inside Composer container

Tags: docker, composer-php, root, user-permissions

I have a basic question when running running a [Composer](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/) in a Docker container.

Is it OK to run the `composer` as user `root` inside the container?
I am confusing that the owner of the created files (for example when using `composer require`) is `root`.

Is run as `root` inside the container OK best practice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using root inside the container is okay, because the container has a lot of dropped privileges.  It can't access hardware or mount paths.  It's essentially a non-privileged user.

Installing the application should definitely be done inside the container.  The `Dockerfile` that builds the image has to install the application to begin with, and that occurs inside the container.  If you're using a container to run a custom application (e.g. php7) that gets built with node and such, a build container that performs the installation is the correct way to isolate the application's update and install behavior from the host system.

Essentially nothing should run outside of a container when deploying an application with Docker.  Any `cron` scripts should run a `docker exec container script.sh` or similar to run periodic jobs inside the container, for example.

Generally, if the application requires root privileges to do something like update modules based on a configuration, I use `docker-compose` to establish a `build` container which does all of that as root and then exits.  I use a `cap-drop` section for the actual application container to remove as many capabilities as possible.

Many applications require `setuid` or `setgid` to drop privileges—e.g. `nginx` requires these so it can change from `root` to `www-data:www-data`.  `nginx` will fail if it comes up as user `www-data`.  The application *should* drop those capabilities after making the change itself.

Answer (score -10):

A docker container should probably only be used to run an application. Anything that installs the application should be done outside the container.

You usually provide a configuration that points the container to production files stored somewhere. That would be the entry point for anything that got installed by Composer as well. The container itself should have no write permissions anywhere, with the exception of any cache directory.

Comment: dockerized applications should be self-contained, and not depend on the host environment to run them

Comment: Now the question is: How is a container created, including the application inside. Should that container create itself? Who's updating all the included system libs that may get updates, often critical security updates? You'd still need something that creates docker container outside of that container. Why doesn't that "something" also put the application into the container in a runnable state?